# Как сделать полную перезаписать строки в PostgreSql?

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, postgresql, jdbc

Есть запрос, выполняемый через JDBC, например :

```
 INSERT INTO TableName( id, name, phone) VALUES ('1', 'new_name', '12345');
```

Запись с таким ключом уже существует, и возникает:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "TableName_pkey"
```

как сделать полную перезапись всей записи, если запись с таким ключом уже существует?

Думал можно использовать:

```
ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE
```

но в данном случае нужно указывать какие поля нужно обновлять.

Но нужно сделать полную перезапись строки.

Comment: удалить и снова добавить?

Comment: А зачем вы делаете инсерт, если хотите сделать апдейт? Зачем нужно перезаписывать?

Comment: он не хочет указывать поля для обновления, видать хочется через инсерт, тогда только с удалением. Но лучше в данном случае апдейт

Comment: Немного уточню. Данные мне приходят в виде JSON (из Kafka) и из него генерится insert. Когда приходит измененная запись, чтобы отдельно не писать код для генерации update, проще перезаписать заново всю запись через insert.

Comment: полностью заменить всю запись.

Comment: удалите предыдущую запись и вставляйте новую или пишите код для апдейта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если прям SQL, и вот прям не хотим проверять предварительно факт наличия записи (хотим в одном запросе все уместить), то для PostgreSql исользуем такую конструкцию

```
INSERT INTO TableName( id, name, phone) VALUES ('1', 'new_name', '12345')
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET name = 'new_name', phone = '12345' WHERE id ='1'
```

Comment: Если вы используете Java, то нужно проверять ключ перед сохранением в базу данных используя простую логику, нет ключа вставляем, есть ключ обновляем. Или можно использовать ORM фреймворк. См. [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/837032/204920)

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас известен первичный ключ, то надо делать обновление, а не вставку. Правильно будет

```
UPDATE TableName set name='new_name', phone='12345' where id='1';
```

Comment: у меня запрос на вставку формируется из json. Приходит json объект, парсится, и из него код формирует запрос, с учетом вложенных объектов (связей таблиц) и прочего. Соответственно, нужно писать другой код, который будет формировать запрос на обновление. Вот я и ищу, как это проще решить.

Comment: @ЛеонидДубравский если у вас известно значение ключа, то нужно делать обновление, если нет, то вставку. Новые объекты создаются после генерации ключа, это можно делать в базе или же использовать генератор ключей, но надо отличать новые объекты от старых. Если возникают конфликты с ключами, то это значит, что данные дублируются или же их надо обновлять. Это зависит от метода используемого при запросе.

Comment: у меня ключ приходит вместе с данными, он не генерируется при первой записи данных. Но я так понимаю, корректно все же делать проверку на наличие по ключу и если он есть - формировать запрос на обновление. Если нет записи по ключу - формировать запрос на вставку.

Comment: основная функция генератора ключей - это уникальность, то есть не может быть у двух разных объектов одинаковых ключей. Поэтому вставки данных с такими ключами безконфликтны, проверку надо делать не только ключа но и всего объекта перед обновлением.

Comment: суть этих всех записей, это перенос данных из одной базы через брокер kafka в другую базу. Мне записи приходят уже с уникальными ключами. Единственное, что записи иногда приходят с обновлениями (на обновление приходит также полная запись), и тогда их нужно пересохранить.

Comment: Тогда вам нужно проверять наличие ключа в базе перед обновлением.